# Skew operator Squared Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I have a linear algebra question that is a proof and I am unsure how to approach this problem.

> For any vector $s$, show that $$(s\times)^2 = ss^T-s^TsI$$ where the skew operator $s\times$ is defined by $$s\times\triangleq\begin{bmatrix}0&-c_s&b_s\\c_s&0&-a_s\\-b_s&a_s&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: There only seems to be one line of text in that picture, so it should be simple enough to transcribe it. But it also does not seem to define what anything is, which would be necessary for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Gooood Latex!  Now, what is $(s \times)$?  Does $\times$ here mean vector cross product? Also, I suspect you mean $(ss^T - s^Ts)I$, am I right?

Comment: Having dwelt more on the problem, I now see that will indeed meant $ss^T - s^TsI$!

Comment: (sx) is the skew operator, I have updated the question with an image showing the definition. The question is as posted. The I is not multiplied throughout just the one term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to show

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -c & b \\ c & 0 & -a \\ -b & a & 0\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c\end{bmatrix}-(a^2+b^2+c^2)\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

What's wrong with simplifying both sides and seeing that they're the same?

---

You should *already* understand the following:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a^2  & ab & ac \\ ba & b^2 & bc \\ ca & cb & c^2\end{bmatrix}$$

$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a^2+b^2+c^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a^2+b^2+c^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a^2+b^2+c^2\end{bmatrix}$$

This is simply how matrix multiplication and scalar multiplication work.

Comment: I tried doing that in matlab but the output I get doesn't look the same

Comment: Is there another way to do a proof without just using brute force to solve this?

Comment: @will Brute force? The simplification is entirely mechanical, taking no thought to do, and to boot also takes less than a minute by hand. You know how matrix multiplication works don't you?

Comment: What I am unsure of is subtracting a vector from the matrix, would I subtract that vector from each term of the matrix?

Comment: @will You are subtracting one matrix from another matrix...

Comment: For my solution I wrote S as a row vector so a row vector multiplied by a column vector would be a row vector. The question doesn't state whether the vector S begins as a row or column vector but I assumed row

Comment: @will Well, you have to choose between assuming $s$ is a row vector versus assuming it is a column vector. If you assume $s$ is a row vector then you get a scalar minus a matrix, and the $I$ is superfluous, that doesn't make any sense. If you assume $s$ is a column vector then you get a matrix minus a scalar times the identity matrix. That makes sense, so obviously you have to go down that route.

Comment: Okay I understand, thanks you helped a lot!